# Sending a post request to Flask (form submit) with AJAX, 405 error, possible CORS issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, post, flask-cors

I am trying to send a POST request from a form submit using Ajax, jQuery on the client side. Processing the submitted data with Flask on the server side.

First I will show the post request which is met with a 405-method not allowed error message.

```
$("#lucky-form").submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
console.log("running this form")

var form = $(this);
var actionUrl = form.attr('http://127.0.0.1:5000/numberapi');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: actionUrl,
    data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function(data)
    {
      alert(data); // show response from the php script.
    }
});
```

I have installed flask_cors and enabled CORS(app) to enable Cross Origin requests (AJAX). The error i believe is not in the flask route itself, as the POST request is not allowed to access, due to the 405. and I have tested it with a GET and get a status 200 OK html response.

I believe this is an issue with the request being sent out on the JS/jQueryside, but am unsure what it may be. Would appreciate your help very much.

For more detail and context here is my Flask route that should receive and process the POST request.

```
@app.route("/numberapi", methods=['GET','POST'])
@cross_origin()
def get_lucky_number():
"""recieves our AJAX request from the front end,"""
## here we will store the data of the users who use our lucky number app. 
#this is just for reference, and we can use the data at a later point. 
#when all of the inputted data is correct, we return the client with a lucky number and the fact
#we can collect data like what type of facts people want to know the most. 
form = LuckyNumberForm()
converted = json.loads(bytes.decode(request.data))
birth_year = converted.get('birth_year')
color = converted.get('color').lower()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    print("validated!")
    if  color not in valid_colors:
          print("error of color")
          form.color.errors = "Please pick a valid colour"
          retrieved = jsonify(errors=form.color.errors) 
          #currently returning undefined.
    
    elif valid_dob(birth_year) != True:
         print("error of dob")
         form.color.errors = "Please pick a valid birthyear between 1900 and 2000"
         retrieved = jsonify(errors=form.birth_year.errors)   
         #currently returning undefined
    else:
         
         year_fact = get_dob_fact(birth_year)
         number_fact = get_number_fact()

    print(year_fact) #this is json
    print(number_fact) #this is json
    return [year_fact,number_fact]


return "csrf validation did not pass"
```

Answer (score 0):

[405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/status/405) error code means used method is not allowed.

You have to allow `POST` method on the route, like this:

```py
@app.route("/", methods = ["POST"])
def index():
  ...
```

Comment: Appreciate that, actually it was a typo, i left out the app route in the flask route code snipped. my aplogies this has been amended now with the missing "@app.route("/numberapi", methods=['GET','POST'])
@cross_origin()"